# Help me understand the following equality $\mathbb{E} [e^{\lambda a_i g_i}] = e^{\lambda^2 a_i^2/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

we are given a standard Gaussian random variable $g_i$ and a real value $0<=a_i<=1$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Why is  $\mathbb{E} [e^{\lambda a_i g_i}] = e^{\lambda^2 a_i^2/2}$?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Then, for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{t X}]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{t x}f_X(x)\:dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{t x}e^{-x^2/2}\:dx=\frac{e^{t^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-{(x-t)^2/2}}\:dx=e^{t^2/2}.$$
Therefore, for all $\lambda, a \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda aX}]=e^{\lambda^2a^2/2}.$$

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. May you please explain why $f_X(x)=e^{-x^2/2}$?

Comment: A density for standard Gaussian RVs $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$.

Comment: Ah ok thank you! I think I got confused because we were not looking at X but $e^{tx}$.